# SharePoint SuiteBar Menu Customization

Tags: c#, sharepoint, drop-down-menu, sharepoint-2013

I am looking to customize the drop down menu at the top of my SharePoint site. I am using 2013, but I am sure a solution from earlier versions of SP will be similar or the same.

I have already customized the Suite bar to including more links -- following this article: http://www.sharepointjohn.com/sharepoint-2013-adding-links-suite-bar-newsfeed-skydrive-sites-overriding-suitelinksdelegate-delegate-control/

**Now what I am trying to customize is the user's menu.. when you click it you get the options "About Me" and "Sign Out". **

Does anyone know of a way to add items to this drop down menu?

Answer (score 1):

1. Open 'C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\TEMPLATE\CONTROLTEMPLATES\welcome.ascx
2. <`SharePoint:MenuItemTemplate runat="server" ID="Title of the item" 
   Text="<%$Resources:wss,personalactions_Title%>" 
   Description="<%$Resources:wss,personalactions_Title_description%>"
   MenuGroupId="100" 
   Sequence="100"
   UseShortId="true" />'
3. Go back to your site refersh the page and you should be good.

Thanks.